# why is .innerHTML changed before xmlhttp.open() and .send()?

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I am learning to use xmlhttprequest/AJAX. In this sample code from w3schools, I do not understand why this line:

```
document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
```

precedes this:

```
 xmlhttp.open("GET","demo_get.asp",true);
 xmlhttp.send();
```

The way I'm thinking about it, you should send the GET request before you have any responseText to do anything with. Where is the error in my understanding?

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function loadXMLDoc()
{
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","demo_get.asp",true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<h2>AJAX</h2>
<button type="button" onclick="loadXMLDoc()">Request data</button>
<div id="myDiv"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The line in question is inside of `xmlhttp.onreadystatechange`, which is a function. Note how it is used:

```
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function ()
{
    ...
}
```

In this case, it is a callback function - it is called when the ajax request (aka `xmlhttp.send()`) completes.

You might want to brush up on your javascript before you dive into ajax.

Comment: I learn as I go :) Given current requirements for school and research, I have very little choice.

Comment: "it is called when the ajax request completes" -> Not exactly :-) It's fired everytime the state changes. List of states: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XMLHttpRequest#readyState

Answer (score 2):

You have just discovered the **asynchronous** part of the AJAX word :-)

Even though the `.send()` method is called later, the `innerHTML` call is made earlier.

How come that works?!

Because an AJAX call is **asynchronous**. Thus, it's not like making a database call in PHP: you make your call, waits for the result, and work with it. Nope.

In JS, for AJAX calls, you define a *callback* function. It is a function that will be called *once the response has arrived*.

For the XMLHttpRequest object, it is the `onreadystatechange` event that is fired when the response comes back. If you register a function in this event, this function will be called *when the response will come back*.

P.S.: the function in `onreadystatechange` won't exactly be fired once the response comes back, but this was for the sake of the explanation. To know when this event is fired, take a look at the [different states](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XMLHttpRequest#readyState).

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't. Consider this code:

```
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
```

It doesn't execute the code inside the function, it only creates the function and assigns it to a property. The function will be executes by the XMLHTTP object when the state changes, and it will catch the state change that means that the response has arrived.